# Is it possible to link slds to an embedded chat deployment?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, slds, pre-chat, embedded

I am building a chat deployment to be embedded on an external site. I created a custom prechat form using aura/lightning components that rely on styling from slds.  When embedded in the external site, none of the styling appears.  Is there a way to link to slds without uploading the entire slds style sheet to the site?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195001/how-to-use-slds-css-as-hosted-static-resource-in-web-to-lead

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I think you need to include the entire SLDS stylesheet in order to have it work correctly.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/123722)

Comment: I think the answer is "No, you can't do that". How should I have worded that differently?

Comment: It's a little more nuanced than that. It is possible to link to SLDS from an external app. You do need the entire CSS et al to live somewhere in order to link to it but it doesn't have to be uploaded to the external site. The question and your answer could use some clarification.